# Need to search API output in JSON format for value and print entire array content

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-sheets

I have googlesheets functions that parse json and import to sheets, you can find the code for the function in ImportJson file.

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

The functions is pretty simple and self explanatory . Disclosure I got this function from here. "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXKhVQU37WM"

I had some additional requirements that this function cannot do. Need to search API output in JSON format for value and print entire array content.

For example I had a JSON output as below .

```
{
  "symbol" : "AAPL",
  "historicalDCF" : [ {
    "date" : "2019-03-30",
    "Stock Price" : 190.5064,
    "DCF" : 199.51439324614452
  }, {
    "date" : "2018-12-29",
    "Stock Price" : 156.4638,
    "DCF" : 165.25974241335186
  }, {
    "date" : "2018-09-29",
    "Stock Price" : 224.6375,
    "DCF" : 233.0488839004929
  }, {
    "date" : "2018-06-30",
    "Stock Price" : 184.3734,
    "DCF" : 192.36145120758877
  }, {
    "date" : "2018-03-31",
    "Stock Price" : 163.5502,
    "DCF" : 172.0839412239145
  }, {
    "date" : "2017-12-30",
    "Stock Price" : 168.339,
    "DCF" : 178.05212237708827
  }, {
    "date" : "2017-09-30",
    "Stock Price" : 149.7705,
    "DCF" : 160.23613044781487
  }, {
    "date" : "2017-07-01",
    "Stock Price" : 139.1847,
    "DCF" : 150.3852802404117
  }, {
    "date" : "2017-04-01",
    "Stock Price" : 138.8057,
    "DCF" : 148.7456306248566
  }, {
    "date" : "2016-12-31",
    "Stock Price" : 111.7097,
    "DCF" : 120.02897160465633
  }, {
    "date" : "2016-09-24",
    "Stock Price" : 108.0101,
    "DCF" : 116.70616209306208
  }
   ] 
    }
```

You can also check live version of this API on this link " https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/historical-discounted-cash-flow/AAPL?period=quarter"

To get DCF value on "2019-03-30", I can simply use functions as this:

```
=IMPORTJSON("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/historical-discounted-cash-flow/AAPL?period=quarter","historicalDCF/0/DCF")
```

What if I need to search through date and get the value of Stock Price? For example I need to get the value of Stock price and DCF on this date "2017-09-30" . How could I do it without knowing array position ?

So for this I need help either by creating new function or modifying existing function to get this functionality.

Help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance to all the gurus out there.

Comment: You are running this in Apps Script right? Why is this tagged as `node.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create a custom function that will:

- Accept a `url`, a `xpath` and a `date` as a parameter.
- Call `IMPORTJSON` and pass the previous `url` and `xpath` as parameters.
- In the JSON returned by `IMPORTJSON`, find the item in `historicalDCF` whose `date` matches the one passed as a parameter.
- Return its corresponding `Stock Price`.

If all of the abose is correct, then you could do something along the following lines:

```js
function GETSTOCKPRICE(url, xpath, date) {
  var jsonData = IMPORTJSON(url,xpath);
  var historical = jsonData["historicalDCF"];
  var stockPrice;
  for (var i = 0; i < historical.length; i++) {
    if (historical[i]["date"] === date) {
      stockPrice = historical[i]["Stock Price"];
      break;
    }
  }
  return stockPrice;
}
```

And then, you can use this function in your sheet by passing it the correct parameters. For example, if you want to get the stock price corresponding to `2017-09-30`:

```
=GETSTOCKPRICE("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/historical-discounted-cash-flow/AAPL?period=quarter", "historicalDCF/0/DCF", "2017-09-30")
```

#### Notes:

- Methods like `filter` or `find`, arrow functions and declarations like `const` won't work here, since Apps Script doesn't currently support ES6.
- You could also modify `GETSTOCKPRICE` so that it only accepts `date` as a parameter, and the call to `IMPORTJSON` has its parameters hard-coded (this would make sense if you're always going to use `IMPORTJSON` for this exact `url` and `xpath`). But that's up to you.

I hope this is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

json.historicalDCF.filter((el) => el.date === "2017-07-01") will return the object that matches that date.

You could get the return like:

```
function findByDate(dateParam) {
  return json.historicalDCF.filter((el) => el.date === dateParam)

}

var theInfoIWantVariable = findByDate("2017-1-1-make-sure-this-is-a-string")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your IMPORT function is returning a JSON object (and assuming the format is what you've shown in your post), then you could simply use a regular javascript `filter()` function to get the specific date you want:

```
const data =IMPORTJSON("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/historical-discounted-cash-flow/AAPL?period=quarter","historicalDCF");
// now, data is the JSON array containing the historical data. All the data. We can filter it for whatever we want.
const myOneDayRecord = data.find( record => record.date === '2016-03-30' );
// so the variable myOneDayRecord is the specific record by date we wanted. Now we can use it as a normal javascript object.
console.log(`So on ${myOneDayRecord.date}, the stock price was ${myOneDayRecord["Stock Price"] } and the DCF was ${myOneDayRecord.DCF}`);
// note that, in the above line,I had to use bracket notation to get to the 'Stock Price' property. That's because of the space in the property name.
```